# Difference between compilation flag -I. and without -I. in GCC

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

Suppose, I have 4 files(t1.c, t2.c, t3.c, t.h).

```
gcc -o test t1.c t2.c t3.c
gcc -o test t1.c t2.c t3.c -I.
```

Here, both give no error and give correct result.

We know that `-I.` is included so that gcc will look in the current directory (.) for the include header file

What is difference between above two statements according to their outputs?

Comment: why gives downvote for this question? I have a query. If you have an answer for it, then give it.

Comment: `-I.` is almost always wrong.

Answer (score 3):

"-I." will make any include statement like

```
include <stdio.h>
```

look for stdio.h in the current folder before the version you have installed in for example /usr/include/ etc.

So if your folder only contain (t1.c, t2.c, t3.c, t.h) then there won't be a difference. Furthermore, you do not need to add "-I." for gcc to find t.h if you include it with:

```
include "t.h"
```

instead of

```
include <t.h>
```